# How can I see why titanium app crashes on Blackberry simulator

Tags: titanium, blackberry-10

I do a Titanium application that woks on iOS and android. Now, I want to create the Blackberry version.

I've tried with a simple app and it's launched well at simulator, but when I've tried my app it doesn't work.

It launches splash screen and begins to load the elements, but I think the app crash because simulator returns to main screen, there isn't any alert (like on android when app stop unexpectedly), it only returns to main screen.

My problem is that I don't know what happen and I can't find any error logs...

I connect by telnet to the simulator, and there I can see the first traces of my app, but any error.

Do you know what can be happened? How can I know if I have an error? How can I know if my app has crashed?

Sorry, if it's an easy question, I'm newbie at Blackberry.

I'm using Titanium SDK 3.2.2 and Blackberry SDK 10.02

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new project (with Titanium SDK 3.1.3 instead of Titanium SDK 3.2.2) and copy all files there. I've tried to launch the app many times, and one of them, the app launches.

Maybe it was a computer or simulator problem.